# vite 2 production env ref element is undefined with compostion api

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vite

I use vue3 with composition api, but when I build my project, the ref element always undefined.

I reproduced it, maybe I used it incorrectly, but I don't know why.

1. I defined a ref in hooks function.

```js
const isShow = ref(false)
const rootRef = ref<HTMLDivElement>();

export default function () {
  function changeShow() {
    isShow.value = !isShow.value;
    console.log(isShow.value, rootRef.value);
  }
  return { isShow, rootRef, changeShow };
}
```

2. Use `rootRef` in the `HelloWorld.vue` and linked element.

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
import useShow from "../composables/useShow";

const { rootRef, isShow } = useShow();
</script>

<template>
  <div ref="rootRef" v-show="isShow" class="test"></div>
</template>
```

3. Create a button in `App.vue` and bind click function.

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
import HelloWorld from "./components/HelloWorld.vue";
import useShow from "./composables/useShow";

const { changeShow } = useShow();
</script>

<template>
  <button @click="changeShow">切换</button>

  <HelloWorld />
</template>
```

When I click button, it works.

[image]

But when I build it and import from lib, it doesn't work.

[image]

My `vite.config.ts` is as follows:

```js
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],

  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": path.resolve(__dirname, "src")
    }
  },

  build: {
    cssCodeSplit: true,
    sourcemap: true,
    lib: {
      entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/index.ts"),
      name: "my-project",
      fileName: format => `my-project.${format}.js`
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      external: ["vue"],
      preserveEntrySignatures: "strict",
      output: {
        globals: {
          vue: "Vue"
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

I think the problem is the definition of `rootRef`. It seems that only binding location can use it. This is no different from defining it in a component. I need to use it in multiple places.

Oddly, in this way, the Dev environment works fine, but Pro env is not available.  Do I need to modify the build configuration of vite.

How do I do that?

Comment: @tony19 I created it, [url](https://github.com/jeremyjone/vite-test-problem).  Thx.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `App.vue` uses its own copy of `composables/useShow` instead of the one from the lib.

The solution is to export the composable from the lib so that your app can use the same one:

```js
// src/index.ts
import { default as useShow } from './composables/useShow';

//...

export default {
  //...
  useShow
};
```

In `App.vue`, use the lib's composable:

```js
import MyProject from "../dist/my-project.es";

const { changeShow } = MyProject.useShow();
```

[GitHub PR](https://github.com/jeremyjone/vite-test-problem/pull/1)

Comment: Appreciate it.  But I don't think this way is suitable for me. I'm creating a component library that is invoked internally, rather than by throwing methods for global use. I'll follow your mind and try to find the answer.